# Kerberos HBase Zookeeper fails

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper, kerberos

I'm trying to kerberise my HBase Cluster and I get some problems with Zookeeper. When I start Hbase I get this error on the Master log :

```
ERROR [main-SendThread(X.X.X.X:2181)] client.ZooKeeperSaslClient: An error: (java.security.PrivilegedActionException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Server not found in Kerberos database (7) - LOOKING_UP_SERVER)]) occurred when evaluating Zookeeper Quorum Member's  received SASL token. Zookeeper Client will go to AUTH_FAILED state.

ERROR [main-SendThread(X.X.X.X:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: SASL authentication with Zookeeper Quorum member failed: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: An error: (java.security.PrivilegedActionException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Server not found in Kerberos database (7) - LOOKING_UP_SERVER)]) occurred when evaluating Zookeeper Quorum Member's  received SASL token. Zookeeper Client will go to AUTH_FAILED state.

DEBUG [main-EventThread] zookeeper.ZKWatcher: master:16000-0x16c236187be0000, quorum=Y.Y.Y.Y:2181,X.X.X.X:2181, baseZNode=/hbase Received ZooKeeper Event, type=None, state=AuthFailed, path=null
DEBUG [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Close called on already closed client
```

On the Zookeeper log, I get :

```
WARN  [QuorumPeer[myid=0]/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:2181] quorum.Learner: Unexpected exception, tries=0, connecting to /X.X.X.X:2888
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.Learner.connectToLeader(Learner.java:229)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.Follower.followLeader(Follower.java:71)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer.run(QuorumPeer.java:937)
```

I verified my firewall, the ports are open

For the configuration, I followed the HBase Reference Guide :

http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#zk.sasl.auth

At first I thought it was a problem with my keytab but Hadoop is working fine with it.

I run HBase 2.0.5, Hadoop 3.1.2 and the Zookeeper is the one provided by HBase.

Comment: Quoting _"Hadoop and Kerberos, the Madness beyond the Gate"_ https://steveloughran.gitbooks.io/kerberos_and_hadoop/content/sections/errors.html the `Server not found in Kerberos Database` probably means "DNS is a mess". Check DNS lookup and reverse-lookup for your ZK host names. And also for your HBase host names. Also, make sure your `krb5.conf` has mapping rules for network domains (and/or specific or host names) to Kerberos realms. And make sure the ZK client library supports IP V6 since that's what you seem to be using...

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter That's kinda weird, I'm actually not using any Domain. I've only set up my hostnames in /etc/hosts so maybe it comes from here ? It was working fine without kerberos so I'm confused.
Also, I don't know why it shows IPV6 addresses, my configuration is set up with v4 addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Following @SamsonScharfrichter 's comment, I've tried a few things :

- I've created and specified in /etc/hosts the FQDN of my servers and modified my configurations to reflect this change.
- Changed the hostname of my servers for the FQDN
- tried to nslookup my hostnames, didn't work since they are specified in /etc/hosts

It didn't do anything, I'm still getting the error. My guess is that Kerberos tries to search for a DNS on my public NIC and not my private. I do not know why it struggles so hard to find my servers, since hadoop has absolutely no problem with it.

EDIT - I set up a private DNS on my network. DNS working great, still getting the error. I'm about to give up

EDIT 2 - I installed tshark on the node with the error. Apparently I get a frame with the message :
Error: KRB5KDC_ERR_C_PRINCIPAL_UNKNOWN
which is weird, I verified my keytab and the principals listed in kadmin. Maybe there defaults principals that I don't use ?